# Why is Sized required when using Self as a type parameter?

Tags: rust, traits

I'm playing around with traits and found that `Sized` is required when using `Self` as a type parameter:

```
trait Foo: Sized { // does not compile without Sized
    type Bar: Baz<F = Self>; 
    type Quiz: Qux<Self>
}

trait Baz {
    type F: Foo;
}

trait Qux<F: Foo> {}
```

Why does is matter to be `Sized` for `Self`? Why is it required to be specified explicitly and what's wrong with not `Sized` type in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For type parameters and associated types, there's an implicit `Sized` trait bound that is set by default. So these are equivalent:

```rust
trait Baz {
    type F: Foo;
}

trait Qux<F: Foo> { }
```

```rust
trait Baz {
    type F: Foo + Sized;
}

trait Qux<F: Foo + Sized> { }
```

For both traits, `F` is required to be sized by default. So when you try to use them in the `Foo` trait, this means that `Foo` needs to be sized as well.

To allow unsized types, explicitly add the `?Sized` trait bound to opt out of the default behavior:

```rust
trait Baz {
    type F: Foo + ?Sized;
}

trait Qux<F: Foo + ?Sized> { }
```

Which allows this to compile without needing to be `Sized`:

```rust
trait Foo {
    type Bar: Baz<F = Self>; 
    type Quiz: Qux<Self>;
}
```